# JavaScript runtime error with HighCharts & MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am trying to use HighCharts with MVC. I have the jQuery and HighCharts scripts referenced. I am getting the following error and can’t seem to fix it.

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addEvent' of
>   undefined or null reference

In the code the error is with the following line in highcharts.js

> d=HighchartsAdapter.addEvent

Any suggestions?

Here’s my View code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/HighCharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var chart1;
    $(document).ready((function () {
        chart1 = new Highcharts.chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series:
            [{
                name: 'Jeff',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0.1, 5, 0.1, 0, 0, 0]
            }]
        });
    }));
</script>
```

Comment: what is your code? Have you tried by .live()?

Comment: Make sure you are loading Highcharts **after** jQuery. Also for debugging, use highcharts.src.js file, not the minified one.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Where does the error come from? (File/line?). Also, can you reproduce the issue in, say, a plunker?

Comment: As mentioned above, the error when debugging is the highchartsadapter.addevent line. Interestingly I ran the exact code today on my work PC (the previous code/error was on a MacBook Pro running windows 7) and did not see an error. The chart still wasn't displayed, but error was thrown.

Comment: Also, I haven't had an issue when running highcharts in a web forms application, just the MVC app.

Comment: As I said - load jQuery before Highcharts. It looks like jQuery or standalone adapter is missing from the project. If this won't help, use `higcharts.src.js` file and then provide **exact** line with the issue. Nobody wants to debug minified file..

Comment: Pawel, jQuery is loaded, see the line right before the highcharts reference.